# Hibernate after 10 minutes of inactivity regardless of CPU Usage?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, task-scheduler

In Windows 10, I can set up the PC to hibernate after certain time of inactivity using Task Scheduler.
But this works when the CPU usage is under certain criterion: this is how Windows 10 defines inactivity.
Can I hibernate PC after certain time (such as 15 minutes) of inactivity regardless of CPU or RAM usage?
What I mean is to determine 'inactivity' solely by keyboard or mouse input.

Comment: Why not just use Windows 10 Advanced Power Settings. Hibernate can be set to Hibernate After Inactivity (Mouse / Keyboard) and should do what you want.

Comment: @John That advanced power setting determines 'idle' status by not only keyboard and mouse input but including CPU usage.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried settings --> system --> power & sleep? That's the usual setting for screen timeout.

Comment: I need to hibernate not just screen out.